# Listing files in Directory in Ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu, dir, readdir

I am trying to list files in the parent directory of the current directory, but when I try to execute this program from terminal I get Segmentation Error.. What am I doing wrong? Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   struct dirent *dirpent;
   DIR *dirp;

   if(argc!=2)
   {
       printf("Cant continue with the program\n");
       return 0;
   }

   dirp= opendir(argv[1]);

   if(dirp)
   {
       while(dirpent=readdir(dirp) !=NULL)
           printf("%s\n",dirpent->d_name);

       closedir(dirp);
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should take the habit to use `errno` when a syscall fails, e.g. by printing `strerror(errno)` in that case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dirpent=readdir(dirp) !=NULL
```

should be

```
(dirpent = readdir(dirp)) != NULL
```

Your current expression is parsed as `dirpent = (readdir(dirp) != NULL)`, which will set `dirpent` to either 0 or 1.

Comment: But it also lists files in the subdirectory of the given directory, how can I display files of only directory I specified not the files of subdirectory also

Answer (score 1):

If you indent your program with `indent rd.c` then compile your program with `gcc -Wall -g rd.c -o rd` you get

```
 rd.c: In function 'main':
 rd.c:21:22: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
 rd.c:21:7: warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]
```

So you forgot parenthesis, your `while` should be

```
 while((dirpent=readdir(dirp)) !=NULL)
```

Please compile your program with all warnings (and improve it till they are all gone) before asking questions. Use the `gdb` debugger (and its `bt` command) to find out why a program crash with `SIGSEGV`.

Don't forget to carefully read documentation like [readdir(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/readdir.3.html) man page and [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) book.

Comment: readdir() displays files of the subdirectory also. How can I prevent files of the subdirectories to get displayed

Comment: Are you really sure of that? According to the `readdir(3)` man page, it should not (and I believe that the GNU Libc `readdir` implementation don't have such a huge bug). Try to `ltrace`, `strace` or `gdb` your program to check.

Comment: yes. I am trying to display files on my Desktop which has 10 files and two subdirectories, But my output contains almost 25+ files, some of which are the files of the subdirectory

Comment: You should trust much more syscalls and low-level libraries than your desktop. What does the `/bin/ls` command shows you? Inspect the output of `strace yourprog` ...

Comment: well. Now I am scratching my head. My desktop displays 10 files, but ls shows 25 files. Why is this so? I am Administrator of the computer and it has no other users..

Comment: I can't help you. I don't really use or trust desktops (just using them to start terminals and firefox). I interact with the system mostly thru `zsh` (and commands). Maybe some files are "backup" (ending with e.g. `~` or `%`) so are not displayed by your desktop...

Comment: May be there is a reason for not trusting desktop?